# PLSQL: Reference to Unintialized collection exception

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

When i am trying to execute a procedure, i am getting an exception Reference to uninitialized collection.

Here is my code.

```
DROP TYPE SCHEMA.STRARRAY;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA.STRARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255);
```

**Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PR_VALIDATE
(
FILEARRAY IN STRARRAY,
PASSARRAY OUT STRARRAY,
FAILARRAY OUT STRARRAY,
)
IS 
--DECLARE
fileName VARCHAR2 (50);

BEGIN
    for i in 1 .. FILEARRAY.count
       loop
        fileName := FILEARRAY(i);  --Here is the exception
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (FILEARRAY (i));
        --many further queries
        end loop
END;
```

Please help what is wrong here.

**Calling code:**

```
EXEC PR_VALIDATE (STRARRAY('abc.txt'));
```

--> This also gives wrong number of arguments even though there is one parameter in IN

Comment: You don't explain how you're calling the pr_validate procedure. Please update your question to provide the calling code as well.

Comment: Thank you..added it but it also throws wrong number of arguments exception. Not sure what is wrong..pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following calling procedure works for me with your procedure (that I had to amend to get to work properly; please make sure your example code compiles before posting!):

```
declare
  farray strarray := strarray();
  parray strarray := strarray();
  flarray strarray := strarray();
begin
  farray :=  STRARRAY('abc.txt'); 

  pr_validate(farray, parray, flarray);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you..Is that something wrong the way i declared? how do i do above with IN parameter

Comment: Your procedure has OUT parameters. That means you need to have something to hold the values of the parameters being returned by the procedure. So, you need to provide variables to hold those variables when you call the procedure. To do it without specifying the out parameters, your procedure would need to be [overloaded](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00807) to only have the in parameter, or just simply remove the out parameters from the procedure..